# Bibliography for Elsevier Journal

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I'm struggling to link the reference for the bibliography according to Elsevier Journal using Latex. Previously, I used the IEEE template and needed to convert it into an Elsevier Journal.

> ```
>     \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
> \bibliography{bibfile}
> ```

According to the template, I used the following package for Elsevier and created the bib file. However, I couldn't cite the reference based on the bib file. Is there a package that I missed? The journal instructions are at the link below.

https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions

Comment: You wrote, "I couldn't cite the reference based on the bib file". Please clarify what you tried to create citation call-outs and the formatted bibliography. Do also state which docoument class you employ, espcially if it's not the `elsarticle` class.

Comment: I'm utilizing `\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{references}
```

And remove this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\end{thebibliography}
```